# how to Secure Oracle APEX application export from updating/copying

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have developed application in Oracle Apex 4.2

I want to give Export of this application and Database as well to one person.

But, I don't want him to be able to Update that application (and database if possible) after Importing at their end.

Is there any possibility that can secure my Oracle Apex Application from modification or copying. In short he must only be able to See application, No update or copying will be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikhil,

Read document related to [Changing Build Status for Multiple Applications.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17556_01/doc/admin.40/e15521/aadm_build_status.htm)

while exporting your application you can choose build status as **Run Application Only**
and export the application, so after import application in another workspace no one can update your application.

This is all about update application.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

(Not yet able to comment on Pars) but nothing is stopping manual edit of the export, which is in text format. It's easy to change the build status before importing.

If you need the developer to install the application, you need to trust them to not edit it.

Comment: you are right scott, that It's easy to change the build status before importing. thanks to pointing that.